# how to change version of standalone mongodb in production enviroment

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I want to change my standalone mongodb version 4.2.0 to 4.2.15 in production environment.
wright now in my ubuntu system mongodb 4.2.0 is install but I want change this version to 4.2.15

Comment: See [Upgrade a Standalone to 4.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-upgrade-standalone/) As you plan to upgrade only minor release, just replace the binaries and restart the mongodb. Be aware, when you install new version, then it may replace your customized `mongod.conf` file with the default. Check the file before you restart the mongod.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.